# Resolution of results exported from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, scale, resolution

I use this code to export my classification result from Sentinel2 images in GEE:

```
// Export the results to Drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: result,
  description: 'Unsupervised Classified Image',
  scale: 20,
  crs: EPSG=32600, 
  region: geometry
});
```

And I also choose 10m as scale while exporting to Google Drive.
I thought I am selecting the output resolution by setting these vlaues to 10.
When I check the information of the exported tiff in QGIS, the Pixel Size is:   [8.983152841195214829e-05,-8.983152841195214829e-05].
How can I obtain the 10m resolution in my output?

Comment: Choose a crs during export which is in meters, like `EPSG:3785`

Comment: Thanks @JonasV. I changed the code in my question to how I changed it but it gives an error : Variable must be declared with "var": EPSG

Comment: `crs: 'EPSG:3785'` should work

Comment: Thanks. I need it in UTM so I wrote 32600, it got run but while exporting I got this error: Error: Projection: The CRS of a map projection could not be parsed.

Comment: Do you know exactly which UTM Zone? I don't think EPSG:32600 is an actual crs which you can use. By the way, you can also reproject the raster you already have exported. The values are likely in degrees, so 8.98e-05 degrees should be about 1 meter at the equator.

Comment: Yes I can do that in QGIS. I thought performing it in GEE might be easier. Thanks. WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N which will be 32633